# Issue injecting room database using dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-2, dagger

I have created my basic Room database structure with just one table `User` and I am trying access by implementing Dagger 2. when i try to access the `UserDao` class from presenter it is null. what is it that I am missing here.

userDao is null in my presenter

```
  @Inject
    UserDao userDao;

  private void testingRoomDatabase() {
        com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User user = new com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User(
                1, "test", "room");
        userDao.insertAll(user); // ****userDao*** is null
        List<com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User> users = userDao.getAll();
    }
```

Room implementation

User

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?
)
```

AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getUserDao(): UserDao
}
```

UserDao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
            "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}
```

Dagger 2 implementation

RoomModule

```
@Module
class RoomModule {

   lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase

    fun RoomModule(app: App) {
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(app.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "demo-db").build()
    }

    @Provides
    @PerApp
    fun providesRoomDatabase() : AppDatabase {
        return appDatabase
    }

    @Provides
    @PerApp
    fun providesUserDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): UserDao {
        return appDatabase.getUserDao()
    }
}
```

AppComponent

```
@PerApp
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class,
        RoomModule.class
})
```

Any suggestions are very helpful

Thanks
R

Comment: I didn't saw your code ``` ((TestApplication)getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);```.  doing this. check https://raacker.github.io/blog/android/android-using-room-as-database-with-dagger2 this link. This will help you to understand how to inject

Comment: Hi Krishna, I do have that in my Fragment on create method

Comment: Great but you are using ```@Inject
    UserDao userDao;``` in your presenter. Inject in your fragment and pass it to the presenter

Comment: How are you creating the component?

Comment: @KrishnaSony Injecting dao into the fragment and passing it to the presenter is a violation of SOLID principles. The easiest solution would be to move the userdao in the constructor and do constructor injection by add `@Inject` to the constructor of the presenter. Then `@Inject` the presenter into the fragment as a field.